# How to Fix Labels and Entries Inside Tab

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I write labels and entries inside notebook tab, however it doesn't lined up vertically. Instead, it's horizontal.

I tried using grid, but it doesn't work because:

_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!notebook.!frame which already has slaves managed by pack

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class View:

    def __init__(self, root):

        # Define software title
        root.title("Plotting Management System")

        # Define software's width and height
        root.geometry("800x600")

        # Define label
        L0 = Label(root, text="Plotting Management System", font="Helvetica 24 bold")
        L0.grid(row=0)
        L0.pack(anchor="nw")

        tab_parent = ttk.Notebook(root)

        tab0 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)

        tree0 = ttk.Treeview(tab0)
        tree0["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three", "four")
        tree0.heading("#0", text="Kode Dosen", anchor="w")
        tree0.column("#0", minwidth=0, width=100, stretch=NO)
        tree0.heading("one", text="Nama Dosen", anchor="w")
        tree0.column("one", minwidth=0, width=300, stretch=NO)
        tree0.heading("two", text="JFA", anchor="w")
        tree0.column("two", minwidth=0, width=100, stretch=NO)
        tree0.heading("three", text="Prodi", anchor="w")
        tree0.column("three", minwidth=0, width=80, stretch=NO)
        tree0.heading("four", text="KK", anchor="w")
        tree0.column("four", minwidth=0, width=80, stretch=NO)
        tree0.pack(anchor="w")

        L1 = Label(tab0, text="Kode Dosen")
        L1.pack(side="left", anchor="w")
        E1 = Entry(tab0, width=50)
        E1.pack(side="left")

        L2 = Label(tab0, text="Nama Dosen")
        L2.pack(side="left", anchor="w")
        E2 = Entry(tab0, width=50)
        E2.pack(side="left")

        L3 = Label(tab0, text="JFA")
        L3.pack(side="left", anchor="w")
        E3 = Entry(tab0, width=50)
        E3.pack(side="left")

        L4 = Label(tab0, text="Prodi")
        L4.pack(side="left", anchor="w")
        E4 = Entry(tab0, width=50)
        E4.pack(side="left")

        L5 = Label(tab0, text="KK")
        L5.pack(side="left", anchor="w")
        E5 = Entry(tab0, width=50)
        E5.pack(side="left")

        tab_parent.add(tab0, text="Data Dosen")
        tab_parent.pack(fill="both")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    gui = View(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I want them to lined up vertically, not horizontally.

Wanted Result:

Label 1 | Entry 1

Label 2 | Entry 2

Label 3 | Entry 3

Actual Result:

Label 1 | Entry 1 | Label 2 | Entry 2 | ...

Comment: Your notebook tab is not showing. Did you forget to put `tab.add()` somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to write the full code. Let me edit first.

Comment: There you go. I have edited it.

Comment: Your code is not a minimal working example (e.g. missing `import`, missing `__main__()`, wrong indention). Copy and Pasting the code does not work for me - if it would, it would be a minimal **working** example. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added import and __main__()

Comment: Look over there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662163/how-to-fix-labels-and-entries-inside-tab

Answer (score 2):

As the error shows, you cannot mix `grid` and `pack` with the same parent. But you can add another frame using `pack`, and have your `Label` and `Entry` widgets using `grid` as the geometry manager inside that frame.

```
class View:
    def __init__(self, root):
        ...
        label_frame = ttk.Frame(tab0)
        label_frame.pack(anchor="w")

        L1 = Label(label_frame, text="Kode Dosen")
        L1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        E1 = Entry(label_frame, width=50)
        E1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        ...
```

Also I recommend using a for loop to create your Label/Entry pairs. It can save you from repetitive codes:

```
for num, i in enumerate(("Kode Dosen","Nama Dosen","JFA","Prodi","KK")):
    a = Label(label_frame, text=i)
    a.grid(row=num, column=0)
    b = Entry(label_frame, width=50)
    b.grid(row=num,column=1)
```

If you need the value of the `Entry`, you can append them to a list during the loop.